# C: printf does not output immediately

Tags: c

I started learning C today through YouTube and I copied the code from a tutorial for testing and I get a completely different result.

My code:

[image: It's supposed to ask for a user prompt to enter a value, the print that value with a different message]

However, whenever I try to run the code, the user prompt doesn't show up and when I enter "3" as an answer, this happens [image]

[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EA8K2d3USDc&list=PL_c9BZzLwBRKKqOc9TJz1pP0ASrxLMtp2&index=12&ab_channel=CalebCurry&t=317s) to YouTuber's code with the timestamp.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Don't post images of code here.

Comment: Add `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf` statement. Output is buffered, differently on different systems.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Sheesh.  You have to do that for every printf statement?

Comment: @RobertHarvey nope, but there is no newline which might do the same job. I would have thought you are aware of this issue, or were you prompting a fuller comment/answer?

Comment: Add `'\n'` at the end of the first printf.

Comment: Please do not learn C from YouTube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `scanf` to wait for user input, it will wait until you give some input to the program.

`printf` doesn't put all of the characters to the screen immediately, it buffers it's output. And as long as your program doesn't terminate or you don't call `flush(stdout)`
to flush the buffer or you don't put newline character `\n` at the end of first parameter to printf the output won't be printed to the screen.

change your call to `printf` to:

`printf("Enter radius\n: ")`
use newline so that the string is printed immediately and buffer is flushed

or if you do not want to use newline

`printf("Enter radius: ")
 fflush(stdout)`

call fflush(stdout) to manually flush the output buffers.

Comment: Adding a new line didn't fix the issue but flushing the buffer did, thanks for the help :)

It's strange, I cloned the code as-is onto my sister's MacBook and it worked perfectly without any alterations. I think it may be a compiler issue with Windows.

Comment: @Archive: On some systems (e.g. my Linux machine), calling `scanf` flushes `stdout` for you, because of use-cases like this.  Only a `read` system call that bypasses stdio could have this problem.  But on a standard library that doesn't do that, yeah you'd need to flush.  If the program was running in an IDE or something where `stdout` isn't connected to a real terminal, just a pipe, `stdout` might be full-buffered instead of line buffered, which might explain why a newline didn't work for your Windows system.  (Like if you ran `./program | cat` on your Mac, so stdout goes through a pipe)

Comment: Just tested on Linux, and `strace ./a.out | cat` shows that when stdout is a pipe, scanf doesn't flush stdout before reading input.  We get a `read` system call before any `write`.